# Can't I fix add comments to code of other answers?

Tags: discussion, edits

Simple and straight question, which may not get so straight answer though:

If someone posts code without comments or explanation, is it wrong to add comments to the code, so other users can understand it (instead of just down voting it and moving along)?

Comment: So... what happens if your comments are wrong?

Comment: Well, I think any society should be based on presumption of innocence. Wrong comments can be rejected.

Comment: That's funny.  I suppose you believe in free speech also.

Comment: You should comment on the post and ask for the OP to modify it!

Comment: Ok let me get this straight.. *you* know what OP thinks to the point where you can change the post so that *other users*, that don't understand like you, will understand ?

Comment: Most unfortunatelly, I don't really get your interpretation of the question. I'm talking about *explaining* what lines of the code do, what the variables mean and so on. Not explaining the OP's intentions.

Comment: You should be aware that many people who review suggested edits will reject them even if clarifying the meaning of a post without changing it is in the edit privilege. If you really want to do these edits you might want to wait until you have 2K

Answer (score 6):

For the same reasons that we normally don't change other people's code (especially in answers), we shouldn't add comments to other people's code.  It's their answer, let *them* fix it.

**See Also**
[Should Suggested Edits change the technical content of a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78845)
[Edit other user's answer or give your own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150118/edit-other-users-answer-or-give-your-own-answer)
[Other than reformatting code, should you substantially alter a question's code samples?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75250)

Comment: So in this case should you just add another answer that includes much more detail?

Comment: @Seth: This is referring to editing inline code comments into a question, *not* comments (in the SO sense) on a user's answer.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Oh, I thought it was about inline code comments in *answers*.. I understand what type of comment we're talking about ;-)

Comment: Oh good- and yes, sorry, you're right that I meant answers :-). But in that case, adding comments (to the answer, not the code) would seem to me like a good middle ground